# GLUT: Rendering Mulitple Windows in the loop

Tags: opengl

I am trying to rendering multiple GLUT windows in a loop in my main function.
Before entering the loop, I use the following code to define the window properties.

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
int windows1 = glutCreateWindow("GlutWindow 1");
int windows2 = glutCreateWindow("GlutWindow 2");
```

But I found later, in my loop, when I call

```
glutDisplayFunc (display1);
glutReshapeFunc (reshape1);

glutDisplayFunc(display2);
glutReshapeFunc(reshape2);
```

It will only render the shape in display2 on the windoew2 function.

I also try to render the two images in the loop by putting the all the code below inside the loop

```
int windows1 = glutCreateWindow("GlutWindow 1");
glutDisplayFunc (display1);
glutReshapeFunc (reshape1);

int windows2 = glutCreateWindow("GlutWindow 2");
glutDisplayFunc(display2);
glutReshapeFunc(reshape2);
```

It does render the 2 windows content but it will keep create windows1 and 2 again and again.

So how to let GLUT to render both windows in this case? Is there any function to let glutDisplayFunc (display1) "smartly" knows that it should be rendered in windows1?

Answer (score -1):

`glutDisplayFunc` and friends set callbacks for the *current window*.  You can change the current window using [`glutSetWindow()`](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node18.html#SECTION00053000000000000000):

> glutSetWindow sets the current window; glutGetWindow returns the identifier of the current window. If no windows exist or the previously current window was destroyed, glutGetWindow returns zero. glutSetWindow does not change the layer in use for the window; this is done using glutUseLayer.

So:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
int windows1 = glutCreateWindow("GlutWindow 1");
int windows2 = glutCreateWindow("GlutWindow 2");

...

glutSetWindow(windows1);
glutDisplayFunc (display1);
glutReshapeFunc (reshape1);

glutSetWindow(windows2);
glutDisplayFunc(display2);
glutReshapeFunc(reshape2);
```